# can someone advice a simple documentation on how to configure email server

Tags: email, email-server

I'm new to all this stuff.

There's some documents on my server. A user send email on e.g doc@my.domain and one of document's must be changed(the way it's to be changed is specified in the email). So, first I need is to rise up a email server. Can someone advice me a simple manual on how to configure a email server? For now I don't need something extra-cool, just email-server(as simple as possible) which will be able to recieve email, and there must be an oppotunity e.g. launch .sh script to change documents when a email recieved.

Answer (score 2):

shortest possible [for debian-ish distributions]

install postfix

```
apt-get install postfix
```

in /etc/postfix/main.cf include:

```
mydestination=your.domain.com
```

in /etc/aliases:

```
accountName: "|/some/command/that/will/receive/email/on/stdin.sh"
```

Comment: thanks for answering. where recieved emails will be stored?

Comment: @Eugeny89 wherever you decide to store them - in such case your script needs to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'simple' way to setup an email server.

Assuming you already have a functioning email system that the your server could potentially connect to and your server is not yet configured to route/fetch emails via the existing service - that's a different question - and it only needs an email client - not a server.

You've not provided any information about the constraints and objectives. e.g. what OS is on the server you are trying to send emails from? What languages do you have available? Why do you need an email server rather than just a client?

Depending on the answers to these the answer might be as simple as fetchmail+procmail or a PHP/Perl script.